# Is there a way to set a common set of properties for a group of classes in VBA?

Tags: vba, interface, polymorphism

I am working on a project in [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) where I have a number of classes which are used to query data from various sources. As these classes are similar I am trying to determine if using a common interface and using the `Implements` statement is a feasible option for me. I am fairly new to OOP in general (though I am trying to learn in a non-VBA language), and I understand that OOP in VBA leaves alot to be desired.

The information that I have been reading basically states that you set up your Interface Class, which we will call `IBaseInfo`:

```vb
Public Property Let LocationData(ByRef locDATA As udtLocData)
End Property

Public Property Let ReferenceDate(ByVal dteDATE As Date)
End Property
```

Then you actually implement `IBaseInfo` in your class, which we will call `clsRate5pt`:

```vb
Implements IBaseInfo

Private Property Let IBaseInfo_LocationData(Byref RHS As udtLocData)

End Property

Private Property Let IBaseInfo_ReferenceDate(ByVal RHS As Date)

End Property
```

Where I am getting confused is how I actually access the properties from the object level in a module. What I am getting from the reference on VBA polymorphism at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240846(v=VS.60).aspx) is that I would need to actually declare a variable of type `IBaseInfo`, set it equal to an object of type `clsRate5pt` and access the properties through that variable. Such as:

```vb
Sub TestIFace()

    Dim o5PT As clsRate5Pt
    Dim oInfo As IBaseInfo

    Set o5PT = New clsRate5Pt
    Set oInfo = o5PT

    oInfo.LocationData = '// Some location Data
    oInfo.ReferenceDate = '// Some Reference Date

End Sub
```

Is there a way to set a common set of interfaces for a group of classes in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)? Is `Implements` the way to go, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

It just seems counter-intuitive to access the properties through a different object. If `clsRate5pt` is "implementing" the interface, shouldn't there be a way to access those properties through `clsRate5pt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA doesn't support inheritance ("is a") but does support composition ("has a"), so you could maybe use that approach in this case:

Eg:
Class "clsSettings" has the common properties and any required property value checks you want to implement across your other classes.

Your other classes then have an instance of your "settings" which could be exposed as:

```
objRate5pct.Settings.LocationData
objRate5pct.Settings.ReferenceDate
```

Comment: Thanks Tim... As I understand you I would do something like... `Public Property Get Settings() as clsSettings` to actually expose it in the class? That seems closer to what I was looking for. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

For interface iFooBar

```
Option Explicit
Public Property Get Foo() as String

End Property

Public Property Get Bar() as String

End Property
```

Then, in your class (which we will call cFooBar)

```
Option Explicit
Implements iFooBar

'Other class code

Public Property Get AsiFooBar() as iFooBar
    Set AsiFooBar = me
End Property

'More code
```

Then you could reference the iFooBar methods from a module

```
dim cfb as cFooBar
set cfb = new cFooBar
debug.print cfb.AsiFooBar.Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I stumbled upon it today, and after working a little on it, I think both the previous answers are either wrong or don't answer the question directly, so here's my take to do what the OP wanted.

First, let me say that both your classes `IBaseInfo` and `clsRate5pt` are correctly defined for what you want to achieve (so I won't reproduce their code here).

And yes, you can use an interface in VBA to do what you want to do: guarantee that several classes provide the same basic set of properties, functions or methods (each implemented in their own way).

Now, what's missing is defining and instantiating the object properly:

```
Sub TestIFace()
    ' Define the object you want to use polymorphically, 
    ' by using the interface you want to implement
    Dim oInfo As IBaseInfo 
    '// Instantiate the object by the concrete class you want to use
    Set oInfo = new clsRate5pt 

    ' Finally, access the properties, methods or functions 
    oInfo.LocationData = ...
    oInfo.ReferenceDate = ...

End Sub
```

Now you can create other classes that implement `IBaseInfo` and just replace the class name in the line

`Set oInfo = new ...`

to get new business logic for the `oInfo` object.

Realize though, that since `oInfo` is of type `IBaseInfo`, you only get to use the properties, functions or methods defined in `IBaseInfo`. You could cast `oInfo` to `clsRate5pt` to access further functionality exclusive of that class, but this will increase the coupling of your code, and could defeat the purpose of defining the interface in the first place, which is to be able to switch specific business logic very easily.